# Milonic Menu: Element is not clickable at point. Other element would receive the click

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to automate the selection of an item in a [Milonic](https://www.milonic.com/) menu. I am using code like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
example_menu = driver.find_element_by_id('m_example')
example_menu.click()
# Wait for the "Example Choice" choice to appear
choice_present = expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Example Choice'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(choice_present)
# Click on "Example Choice"
example_choice = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Example Choice')
example_choice.click()
```

However, a WebDriverException is raised with a message like this:

```
Element is not clickable at point (236, 44). Other element would receive the click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use [ActionChains](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=WebElement#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) to move the mouse over the menu entry but click on the [Milonic](https://www.milonic.com/) link:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
example_menu = driver.find_element_by_id('m_example')
example_menu.click()
# Wait for the "Example Choice" choice to appear
choice_present = expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Example Choice'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(choice_present)
# Use an action chain to move to the "Example Choice" but click on the
# Milonic menu link
example_choice = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Example Choice')
mmlink1 = driver.find_element_by_id('mmlink1')
action_chain = ActionChains(driver)
action_chain.move_to_element(example_choice)
action_chain.click(mmlink1)
action_chain.perform()
```